# Display image after uploading in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the situation: An image file is uploaded in a form within an iframe contained in the main document. Upon submitting the form that uploads the file, a handler is called in the main document. Within that handler, I have access to the name of the file uploaded and I know the path where the files are uploaded to. I want to display the image file that has just been uploaded without refreshing the page.

Here's what I tried first:

```
$("#" + dzid).delay(5000).append('<img src="'+path+filename+'">');
```

However, this gives a `NetworkError: 404 Not Found` in the console no matter what delay is set. I thought to add the delay would allow some time for the file to be uploaded but it seems that it looks for the contents of append before doing the delay.

Then I tried:

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#" + dzid).append('<img src="'+path+filename+'">')}, 5000);
```

This actually works, but using a delay time seems like an unreliable approach. Is there a better way?

Comment: Check in `console` what is your path by using `console.log(path+filename);`

Comment: You could keep track of how the upload is going on your server, or just if it's finished, then just poll that using setTimeout and async requests. When it's done, then insert the image.

Comment: I would like to know how you are trying to upload the image ... that would determine what you should do about its events ... if you don't want to use events, like after uploading or something (better), you can use a loop to try and initialize an image until it is initialized and loaded then you exit the loop.

Comment: @CME64: file is submitted by POST to a PHP script that resizes it and saves it in a know location within the website file structure.

Comment: good, why don't you use events then ? like ajax and use the callback (the response from the server) when the image is uploaded to request for the image after it is uploaded .. this will be cleaner than sending requests until it is loaded  ..

Comment: @CME64: What event should I use? The form is submitted in the standard manner - form submit button - not using ajax because it's a file upload. As far as I understand ajax does not work for submitting files in older browsers.